# cURL suppress response body

Tags: curl, output, suppress

Is it possible instruct cURL to suppress output of response body?

In my case, the response body is an HTML page, which overflows the CLI buffer, making it difficult to find the relevant information. I want to examine the other parts of the output such as HTTP response code, headers, e.t.c. - everything *except* the actual HTML.

Answer (score 196):

You can use the `-o` switch and `null` pseudo-file :

#### Unix

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -v http://google.com
```

#### Windows

```
curl -s -o nul -v http://google.com
```

Comment: ... if you are on Unix ;-) For Windows you might want to use nul. Here is the link to the docs, perhaps BaltoStar feels the urge to read before asking next time ;-) http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: You are welcome. But it is "nul", "null" will create a file with that name

Comment: in fact i did read the man page before posting and tried `-s -o nul` but on my windows machine  `curl -s -o nul -v http://{internal-host}/{internal-uri}` outputs page's entire html -- i tried `curl -s -o nul -v http://google.com` and it does suppress output as expected , so i'm not understanding why this doesn't work for my internal site

Comment: `-o` only specifies one URLs output: if you have multiple urls, it will only discard the first :(

Comment: Relies on non-portable `NUL` and `/dev/null`. Using [`-sIXGET`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49669324/429091) is a better option IMO.

Answer (score 95):

Here's a way to suppress all curl output and headers, with the option of still showing errors if they occur. Useful for cron jobs or automated testing.

### Unix

To suppress all output:

```
curl --silent --output /dev/null http://example.com
```

To suppress output but still show errors if they occur:

```
curl --silent --output /dev/null --show-error --fail http://example.com
```

### Windows

To suppress all output:

```
curl --silent --output nul http://example.com
```

To suppress output but still show errors if they occur:

```
curl --silent --output nul --show-error --fail http://example.com
```

### Parameters Explained

`--silent` suppresses the download-in-progress stats (but will still show HTML output)
`--output /dev/null` hides successful output
`--show-error` shows errors, even when `silent` mode is enabled
`--fail` will raise an error if HTTP response is an error code (404, 500 etc.) instead of merely DNS/TCP errors.

---

**UPDATE:** I realise the original author wanted to inspect the headers and response code of a request rather than silencing *everything*. See [samael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49669324/195835) for details on how to do that.

Comment: Relies on non-portable `NUL` and `/dev/null`. Using [`-sIXGET`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49669324/429091) is a better option IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @binki - they actually do different things. Also realised the OP wanted to inspect the headers which don't show in my solution. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I guess in rereading the OP’s post they didn’t say they *only* wanted to see headers. They might actually have been looking for `curl -vo/dev/null`/`curl -voNUL`… and I don’t know if there is a portable variant of that, hrm… ;-).

Comment: Is there a short command for --fail? I think -sS is what we need for both --silent and --show-error

Comment: Yes, there is: `curl -Ssfo /dev/null url`. But be nice to the future maintainers.

Comment: Yes! Finally an answer that works!

Answer (score 67):

When you want to show headers but hide the response body, you'll want to use:

```
curl -sIXGET http://somedomain.com/your/url
```

I'd been using `curl -I http://somedomain.com/your/url` for just showing response headers. The problem with that though is that it makes the request using the [`HEAD` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) which is no good when you want to test an API call that only responds to a `GET` request. This is what the `-X GET` is for, it changes the request to a `GET`.

So, in summary:

`-s` hides the progress bars from output (especially useful when piping to another program)
`-I` shows headers (but makes a `HEAD` request)
`-XGET` converts request back to a `GET` request

see: http://www.woolie.co.uk/article/curl-full-get-request-dropping-body/

Comment: That’s really complicated; `curl -i` does exactly the same thing.

Comment: no, `-i` includes the HTTP-header in the output as well as the body. Try it. `curl -i http://google.com` is not the same as `curl -IXGET http://google.com`

Comment: For my purposes (and the OP's) `curl -I url` is sufficient and has the same effect. I just needed to check if the url was responsive. This question too was merely about suppressing the body, which `HEAD` does well.

Comment: But HEAD / GET may get you a different result. It is not the same. Especially if you need these type of commands to troubleshoot what is happening. I found the suggestion in this answer very helpful. -i and -I is not the same. -I and -sIXGET is not the same.

Comment: `curl -sIG http://...` should also be equivalent to `-sIXGET`

Comment: `-G` is not equivalent to `-XGET` - in fact `-IG` will make a HEAD request.

Answer (score 17):

Just **make a HEAD request.** You will get the headers without the body. A standards-compilant server is supposed to send exactly the same information here as it would to a GET request.

```
curl --head <url>
```

---

**Alternatively,** if a HEAD request doesn't work for you for some reason, **the following will make cURL send a `GET` request but then print response code and headers and drop the connection without receiving the response body** -- unlike other answers which receive and then discard it. This can save a lot of time and bandwidth, especially if the body is very large.

```
curl --head -X GET <url>
```

**You can do likewise with any other verb** (e.g. `POST`) by supplying it to the `-X` option instead of `GET`.

Comment: This doesn't works for POST, and also depends on the implementation of HEAD in the server

Comment: @AllanDeamon doesn't `-X POST` work? `-X` overrides the verb sent but keeps Curl's behavior from `--head` -- receive and show just the response code and headers.

Comment: The server implements the HEADER. I saw many implementations that do not work as intended. But the point here is that the HEADER is equivalent to GET. The correct way to implement is to do everything GET does and then just send the headers. So if you want to trigger the behavior or another verb like POST, the HEAD verb won't work. So when you use --head, instead of sending a GET it sends a HEAD. But you cannot send 2 HTTP verbs.

Comment: @AllanDeamon Maybe I wasn't clear enough. `curl --head -X <verb>` sends `<verb>`, not `HEAD`.

Comment: Yeah, in that case, I suggest you edit the answer to make it more clear, as It seems true to be a valid answer, but other people could have the same misunderstanding as me.

Comment: @AllanDeamon Done.

Comment: I just hit a situation where I normally use `-I` to view the headers and in this case a GET gives me 200/OK and a HEAD request gives me 500/Server Error, so -IXGET was helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to show the response headers and suppress the body:

```sh
curl -sD - https://example.com -o /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following solution:

```sh
curl -sS -i https://example.com | perl -e '$p = 1; while(<STDIN>){ $p = 0 if $_ =~ /^\s*$/; print if $p }'
```

It's a longish one-liner but does what you need:

- the body is suppressed
- the headers & response codes are output @ stdout, so that you can also pipe the info to another command or capture it in a shell variable like `output="$(curl -i ....)"`
- any cURL errors are sent @ stderr
- this works for both GET & POST requests, as well as for any other HTTP request methods, and you can use the other standard `curl` arguments